# How to stop a JS Function from stopping when a user stops a page from loading?

Tags: jquery, ajax, function

I like tried to make a simple page for chat. A function is made:

```
function Update()
{
$.post('update.php',{
some_data:some_data
},function(data,success){
Update();
}
);
}
```

Now, you see as soon as the post request completes, the function is run over again. What this does is check if any new message has been input into the database and if it has, it displays it on the page. So I like want this function to continue executing over and over again. But I noticed, if I click on the cross (X) on the browser that stops the page from loading, the function stops. How to I overcome that? Normally due to the function running over and over again the page loading never stops so if someone stops it manually, the function will stop. How do I stop that? THanks ...

Comment: why not use `setInterval()` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a different approach for that, Javascript has `setInterval()` method that executes a function over and over at an interval you can specify. We need to remove from success the other update call in `Update()` function:

```
function Update() {
    $.post('update.php', {
        some_data: some_data
    }, function (data, success) {
       //logic here but not another Update() call!
    });        
}
```

And add a `setInterval()`calling it every 5 seconds for example (time is measured in milliseconds:

```
setInterval(function(){Update();}, 5000);
```

Example **FIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/KVtbp/